# Fragment webView for Button (to call or dial a number) [Android Studio]

Tags: android, button, webview, fragment, dialing

I have successfully added a `WebView` to a fragment, to load a website. However, some elements on the website, such as a button, link to a `tel=` scheme, resulting in an `err_unknown_url_scheme` error when pressed. How can I support this?

This is my code:

**fragment_notification.xml**

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView3"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</WebView>
```

**NotificationsFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.alidmisli.gcsdriver.R;


public class NotificationsFragment extends Fragment {

    public NotificationsFragment() {

    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false );

        WebView webView= (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView3);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://gcs-bn.com/sos.html/");

        return v;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alidmisli.gcsdriver">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set webviewclient like this

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

String TELPREFIX = "tel:"

class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.startsWith(TELPREFIX)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
```